# IE Edge and Cache control

Tags: asp.net-core, browser-cache, microsoft-edge, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core app where in I am have a APIs with Rest Calls. I try to Cache the response for a few of them using a cache Profile. Somethign like the code below

```
    [Route("RefreshToken")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "token")]
    public IActionResult RefreshToken()
    {return "Blah"}
```

The Cache Profile token is define in my start up like

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default",
                new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = reponseCacheDuration,
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client,
                });
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("token",
                new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = (tokenExpirationMinutes - 1) * 60,
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client
                });}
```

The problem I am having is when I look at the network traffic in IE and Chrome, IE for some reason does not fetch the value from cache. Below is the network traffic in IE Edge (I do have the "Always Refresh from server" set to off)

[Network traffic for IE Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCwIt.png)

and here is the Network traffic from Chrome

[Network traffic for chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PfrN.png)

You see that Chrome fetshes the values from the disk cache while IE fetches it from the server everytime. I use IE Edge.

Also the response headers from RehreshToken rest call is

[Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKV0b.png)

Why isn't IE hitting the cache. The app is painfully slow in IE because it goes to the server for every request. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: To see the images, click on the link and change https to http !

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the real cause of your problem, that is that IE (and Edge) is not caching files, and I've found that the **IE Dev tools has a "Always refresh from server" option that is on by default**. You have to turn this off to be able to watch caching happen in the devtools. Just press f12 , then go to network tab and find the forth button in tool box with this title : Always refresh from server .

[image]

I hope it helps,

Juan

Comment: That option is set to false on I.E. and I double checked that when dev tools are closed but i.e. Still hits my logger at the server every time and nothing is fetched from cache (local cache)